# Voltage Regulator Alternative

Tags: voltage, capacitor, voltage-regulator

I want to use 5v from a 9v battery to charge my mobile.But i dont have a 7805 ic (voltage regulator).Is there any alternative?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: An emitter follower driven by a 5.6 V Zener diode (supplied through a resistor). See this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_regulator#Transistor_regulator).

Comment: Please list all the components you do have.

Comment: It would be rather ineffective and wasteful to use a standard 9V block battery to charge a mobile phone, as it doesn't contain much energy.

Comment: Please explain "don't have". Is it as in "I don't wanna spend a dime" or as is "please my phone is dying right now I have a paper clip and a rubber band help me" (see McGyver)

Answer (score 2):

Go to eBay and get yourself a [ready made switching regulator module](http://www.ebay.com/itm/2pcs-DC-7-24-V-to-5V-2A-USB-Voltage-Power-Converter-Module-For-Phone/370706772793?_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20131003132420%26meid%3Dd19d85234f07421fbd0242c1a59a8685%26pid%3D100005%26rk%3D4%26rkt%3D6%26sd%3D370706773224&rt=nc). They take in the voltage range you have available with your battery and produce a 5V output on a USB connector.

[image]

With this module you'll be able to utilize a much greater part of the energy from your battery for charging the phone due to the high efficiency of the module. If you used a 7805 type approach you will see almost half of the energy from your battery get dispersed as heat.

Answer (score 1):

There are a ton of alternatives - it just depends what you have at your disposal. At the very low end, you could simply drop 4 volts across a resistor, which is extremely wasteful and probably not the best solution. The voltage would, of course, also drop as the battery voltage declines. Your best bet would probably be a simple emitter follower voltage regulator. You could make one of these with 3 components: a resistor, a transistor, and a Zener diode. The circuit looks like the following:

[image]

You can find more information here: http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/power-management/linear-power-supply-psu/series-voltage-regulator-theory-circuit.php

Comment: You can't just drop the voltage across a resistor unless the power draw is constant - which it won't be.

Comment: I realize that. It was just trying emphasize that there are a variety of solutions, with varying degrees of feasibility, depending on the components on hand. Perhaps that was not the best example..

Answer (score 1):

A hamster in a spinning wheel wired with contacts so it produces a series of pulses.  Then connect that to an output cap or maybe a series inductor to an output cap to smooth the voltage to 5V.

The trick is going to be training him to run at the right speed and it might help to have more than one so they can take shifts.

Comment: maybe he can let the hamster sniff some acid from the 9V battery and see if it runs faster.